# TypeError: data is undefined en Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, nodejs

tengo el siguiente codigo el cual me arma una tabla , pero no me la pagina , en la consola me lanza el siguiente error

TypeError: data is undefined

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi codigo

```
  function obtenerReqHistorial()
  {
    let formData= new FormData();
    let filas, cabecera;
    let resultados=[];
    filas="";
    ajaxDinamicoForm("mesa_ayuda/obtenerReqHistorial", formData, function(data)
    {

    console.log(data);
    resultados=data.resultados;


        cabecera="<tr>";
        cabecera+="<th>N°Req</th>";
        cabecera+="<th>Fecha</th>";
        cabecera+="<th>Mandante</th>";
        cabecera+="<th>Sociedad</th>";
        cabecera+="<th>Modulo</th>";
        cabecera+="<th>Prioridad</th>";
        cabecera+="<th>Descripcion</th>";
        cabecera+="</tr>";




    $("#data-table-default").find("thead").html(cabecera);



        for(let i=0; i < data.resultados.length;i++)
        {
            filas+="<tr>"; 
            filas+="<td><a href='mesa_ayuda/detalle?req="+resultados[i].Cod_Requerimiento+"' class='label label-inverse'>"+resultados[i].Cod_Requerimiento+"</a> </td>";
            filas+="<td>"+resultados[i].Fecha+"</td>";
            filas+="<td>"+resultados[i].Cod_Mandante+"</td>";
            filas+="<td>"+resultados[i].Cod_Sociedad+"</td>";
            filas+="<td>"+resultados[i].Cod_Modulo+"</td>";
            filas+="<td>"+resultados[i].Cod_Prioridad+"</td>";
            filas+="<td>"+resultados[i].DescripcionBreve+"</td>";
            filas+="</tr>";
        }


    $("#data-table-default").find("tbody").html(filas);



    if ($('#data-table-default').length !== 0)
    {
        $('#data-table-default').DataTable(
        {
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,

            ajax: {
                url: "mesa_ayuda/obtenerReqHistorial",
                type: 'POST',
                dataSrc: "historial",

            },
            columns: [
                { resultados : "Cod_Requerimiento" },
                { resultados : "Fecha" },
                { resultados : "Cod_Mandante" },
                { resultados : "Cod_Sociedad" },
                { resultados : "Cod_Modulo" },
                { resultados : "Cod_Prioridad" },
                { resultados : "DescripcionBreve" },


           ],
            responsive: true,

            "language":
            {
                "decimal":        "",
                "emptyTable":     "No data available in table",
                "info":           "Mostrando _START_ al _END_ de _TOTAL_ registro(s)",
                "infoEmpty":      "Mostrarndo 0 a 0 de 0 registro(s)",
                "infoFiltered":   "(filtered from _MAX_ total entries)",
                "infoPostFix":    "",
                "thousands":      ",",
                "lengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
                "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
                "processing":     "Procesando...",
                "search":         "Buscar:",
                "zeroRecords":    "No matching records found",
                "paginate": {
                    "first":      "Primero",
                    "last":       "Último",
                    "next":       "Siguiente",
                    "previous":   "Anterior"
                },
                "aria": {
                    "sortAscending":  ": activate to sort column ascending",
                    "sortDescending": ": activate to sort column descending"
                }
            }

        });
    }

    })
}
```

Comment: Revisa si el plugin que estas usando te pide alguna estructura en concreto de como obtener los resultados o revisa si esta parte data:{resultados} es necesaria

Comment: Si te dice que `data` no está definida es porque el callback que le pasas a `ajaxDinamicoForm` no está recibiendo `data`, por ende, el problema ocurre en esa función.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo que veo, el array de resultados esta quedando bien. ¿Evaluaste el resultado de la carga del DataTable? intenta debuggear el resultado, tienes herramientas dentro de este plugin que te pueden ayudar a detertar problemas. [DataTables: 7. Warning: Ajax error](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/7)

También evalúa el Ajax el cual debe retornar datos en tu DataTable

te dejo un ejemplo, para como evaluar.

```
  var request = $.ajax({
  url: "mesa_ayuda/obtenerReqHistorial",
  method: "POST",
  data: "??",
  dataType: "??"

});

request.done(function( msg ) {
  $("#log").html(msg);
});

request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
  alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
```

Comment: el problema era en el darasrc el cual necesitaba el contenedor del array , y el data type , gracias